# Estimates badly wrong on empty string, but not specific value - SQL 2014 or earlier

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Update: I went down the rabbit hole and came out understanding that this is a bug in 2014.  It can be replicated on SQL Server 2019 in compatibility level 120 (2014) but if you flick the compatibility level to 2016 or above it goes away.

Can I make it work in 2014?

I have a table that contains 2 fields that I want to filter on.  The application (which I can't control) inserts an empty value into the row for the one of the columns.

I created a filtered index to return the primary key "where field1 = 'SOMEVALUE' and field2 = ''"

The query has the same criteria - i.e. "where field1 = 'SOMEVALUE' and field2 = ''"

The planner happily uses the filtered index but instead of the correct estimate (1 row) it estimates hundreds of thousands of rows suggesting that it is not considering the statistics for the filter.

If (for the purpose of experimentation) I change the filtered index to "where field1 = 'SOMEVALUE' and field2 = 'N'" - "N" being some arbitrary non-empty value, and change the query to use the same criteria, the planner estimates the exactly correct number of rows.

How can I get the planner to estimate correctly base on the empty string?

EDIT - thanks Erik - I built a whole test table and insert script to replicate it and it didn't replicate until.... I put an empty string into rows that had a different value of field 1 - see below.

```
USE TESTING

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DEMOTABLE](
    [ID] [decimal](19, 0) NOT NULL,
    [FIELD1] [char](12) NOT NULL,
    [FIELD2] [char](60) NOT NULL,
    [FIELD3] [char](60) NOT NULL

 CONSTRAINT [PK_DEMO] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC,
    [FIELD1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;
DECLARE @LASTDIGIT CHAR(1)
--ADD THE SAMPLE ROWS
WHILE @cnt < 100000
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO DEMOTABLE (ID,FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3) VALUES (
    @CNT,
    CHAR(65+CAST(RIGHT(CAST(@CNT AS VARCHAR(20)),1) AS INT))
    ,CAST(@CNT AS CHAR(60) )
    ,CAST(@CNT AS CHAR(60) ))
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;
--NOW ADD THE TEST ROW
   INSERT INTO DEMOTABLE (ID,FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3) VALUES (
    @CNT + 1,
    CHAR(65+CAST(RIGHT(CAST(@CNT + 1 AS CHAR(20)),1) AS INT))
    ,''
    ,'N')
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
--create the indexes

CREATE INDEX FIELD1_FIELD2_FILTERED ON DEMOTABLE (FIELD1,FIELD2) WHERE FIELD1 = 'A' AND FIELD2 = ''
CREATE INDEX FIELD1_FIELD3_FILTERED ON DEMOTABLE (FIELD1,FIELD2) WHERE FIELD1 = 'A' AND FIELD3 = 'N'

--- this will get you an accurate estimate (of 1 row)
SELECT ID FROM DEMOTABLE WHERE FIELD1 = 'A' AND FIELD2 = ''

--this will ruin it
UPDATE DEMOTABLE SET FIELD2 = '', FIELD3 = 'N' WHERE FIELD1 <> 'A'

--now you get an estimate of #rows with FIELD2 = ''
```

Comment: Please post the filtered index definition and [consider following this advice](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/how-to-get-answers-to-sql-server-performance-questions/).

Comment: If you want the query optimiser improvements in 2014 I think you will need trace flag 4199

Comment: Repro on 2014 here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=140ccd3f175b0fd6bf87fe558031710e I note that forcing the legacy estimator on 2019 does not manifest this bug https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=60444f0fd96a9f1d8ffb9fe84b03b5c1 Yes you should probably use TF4199, but ideally just upgrade. Are you on the latest build of 2014 at least?

Comment: Sadly no, on the base. Initial attempts to install sp3 failed with an error. Actually we were starting to cost an upgrade so now there’s an entry on the plus side of the ledger.